# MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, wcf

This is a strange one:

The official MSDN documentation for MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled says it's only a .NET 4.0+ feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.multiplesitebindingsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx

and if you search online for "MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled" you'll find other SO questions and blog postings about people searching for a .NET 3.5 equivalent.

...yet it working for me in my WCF 3.5 application running in a .NET 2.0 Application Pool in IIS, in fact I don't think the server has .NET 4.0 installed at all.

I poked around with Reflector and saw that `ServiceHostingEnvironment.MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled` did exist within the assembly, screenshot proof (bonus: it says it's in the `3.0.0.0` version of the assembly too!)

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone can explain this. This can't be a 3.5 SP1 change as there's no mention of it on the changes page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836419.aspx

Comment: Maybe it's a simple documentation bug

Comment: I haven't used Reflector in a long time, but I noticed that the image for `MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled` is different from most of the other properties....but I'm not sure what all the icons mean.  Maybe there's a clue there?

Comment: Note that in the image you posted, `MultipleSiteBindingsEnabled` is a static read-only property, whereas in .NET 4.0+ it because an instance read-write property.  Since prior to 4.0 it was static read-only, that leads me to believe that it was set somehow in the framework based on other information. That's a SWAG though...maybe even a USWAG...

Comment: @Tim - the Read-only property is on the `ServiceHostingEnvionment` itself, it gets its value from the web.config `<serviceHostingEnvironment>` element correctly. So your comment is moot, I'm afraid.